# Story about scientists on a planet who discover humans already there

Tags: story-identification

What I recall is the story had scientists on a planet who discovered humans were already there. But actually another person preceded them, named General Majustatus. He taught the native beings, who are originally amoeboid in nature how to shape themselves as humans and wage periodic tribal warfare.

The scientists study other life forms which have similar amoeboid morphology. In one scene a scientist tries to dissect a specimen which triggers an exploding quills defense that kills him and another.

The other details are hazy

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Was it in a physical book, an e-book or an online story?  Was it a short story or novel length?

Comment: That's funny... Doing the obvious, a search for "General Majustatus" yields [General Jim Mattis, USMC (ret)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Mattis).

Comment: Thanks DavidW and FreeMan! The story was a novel sized book I read back in the 90s. I thought it was a Heinlein book, but I am remembering it wrong.

Comment: General Majustatus is an uncommon name and I can't find any matches to it.

Comment: Thanks Valorum. Agreed. This question has been with me for a good number of years.